# how to set an array with the size of n to a specific number in brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

I want to set an array of n elements to a predefined value (which isn't copying from a cell but setting a value from the code itself). How could I do that? without changing other cells as I went through after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "an array" you mean a contiguous part of the brainfuck array; and that n is <256 so you can count on fitting n in a cell. In that case, beginning with the memory as "0 n ? ? ? ..." and the pointer at n, you could do something like:

```
[>[-]<-[>+<-] ++++++++++ or whatever >]
```

However, depending how you're going to manipulate this data later, it will often be a good idea to space it out more; e.g. to interleave it with 1s you could do

```
[>[-]>[-]<<-[>>+<<-] ++++++++++ or whatever >+>]
```

With regard to copying a chunk of the array to a different place, the best thing of all is to avoid needing to do that, but if you need to, here's one decent way to do it.

```
[
  ->[>[>>]>+<<<[<<]>-]
  >[>>]>>[>>]+[<<]>
  [>[>>]<+<[<<]<<[<<]>+>[>>]>-]
  <<<[<<]+>>
]
```

This assumes that the current memory layout is

0 ? 1 a 1 b 1 c ... 1 z 0 0 0 ...

where a, b, c, etc are an arbitrary number of arbitrary values, and it assumes that the pointer starts at the leftmost 1 cell. This would be a reasonable way to have set up the memory. In brainfuck it's crucial to choose your memory layout to make things easy for yourself. This code then copies this chunk of memory into the space at the right, producing

0 ? 1 a 1 b 1 c ... 1 z 0 _ 1 a 1 b 1 c ... 1 z 0 ?

where the '_' cell is also 0. This code assumes that the space to the right, that the data is being copied into, is already clear. In brainfuck, you don't want to clear space right before you use it, you want to clear data after you're done with it. You need to have a clear idea of what is where, at any given point in the execution, and not have the memory cluttered with things you've forgotten about.

For each value, this code copies it to the '_' space between the arrays, then adds a 1 marker to the growing right array, then moves the value back to where it started and also into its place in the second array, then goes on to the next value. During the loop it keeps the 1 cell to the left of the value it's copying set to 0 as a marker, then resets it to 1 at the end. This code ends at the 0 cell left of the '_' cell.

Note that if you then wanted to set all of the left "array" to, say, 10, you could just do

```
<<[>[-]++++++++++<<<]
```

Comment: thanks, but when it's going through the array, it changed the array. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that, still. Do you mean: (A) that you want to set these n cells that way without touching the cell after the nth cell? (then set n-1 cells with this code, and the nth manually right after). (B) that you want to be able to modify some of these cells afterward, while leaving most of them untouched? (Spacing them out as with my second code can help with that.) (C) something else?

Comment: you can modify the other cell as you wish but I want it back to its original value after changing them. Also, when other cells in between the start and the target location are not equal to 0, it will have a problem.

Comment: Ah. You want this not to assume that section of array is already cleared. I've updated the code to reflect that. Previous code assumed cell n+1 was 0 and left it as 0; this wipes cell n+1, so again if you have something in cell n+1 that you want to preserve, do n-1 cells with this code and then set cell n separately. Though again, it will often be helpful to space things out a bit more than that.

Comment: well, clearing the cell is easy. I just need to use `[-]` to do the job. But what I want is to not modify the other memory as I went through it (basically setting it back to its original value after.) But thanks a lot for your help though, it did help me.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reconciling how you want to set these n elements to a predefined value, without modifying their values. On the face of it this seems like an contradiction. In brainfuck, the memory is mutable, the same as in C or whatever; if you set variables to a new value, as your question asked, they don't still have the same value they had before that (except maybe coincidentally), and there's no way to recover the previous value unless you copied it somewhere else beforehand.

Comment: If you're wanting to set these n variables to a new value at the same time, and then restore them all, you'll need to copy that whole part of the array to some other part of the array first and then copy it back after. If you're wanting to set them to the mew value one at a time and then restore each one to me its previous value before setting the next, that's not quite doable if the values are contiguous; they need to be spaced out more or you could scan through and gradually displace that section of array by 2 or 3 cells, and then restore it. Need some navigation apparatus in any case.

Comment: If I'm still not getting it, maybe post code in C or some similar imperative language that does the thing you're trying to do in brainfuck?

Comment: I see what you mean. So what is the best way to copy an array? add that to your answer and I will accept it. thanks a lot!

Comment: Done. You might also want to edit the question to also ask that.

Comment: I did, it said here *without changing other cells as I went through after?*. Anyway, thanks.